# UIView cameraOverlayView in Augmented Reality starts in portrait mode

Tags: iphone

I'm doing a bit of AR work here and one of the biggest problem right now is one of my UIView will not respond to any frame settings I make to it.

The code is very similar to this. I've made a few major changes to incorporate into my project:

nurse.site11.com/JaredCrawford-iWVU-632a9a0/Libraries/ARKit/AugmentedRealityController.m

"displayView" is used as a custom UIView that is passed to UIImagePickerController's setCameraOverlayView: method.

Now in the initWithViewController method of that AugmentedRealityController.m file, I have tried setting the displayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMakeFrame(0, 0, 480, 320)];

The problem is, even if I set it to displayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMakeFrame(0, 0, 100, 100)]; the view still remains full screen 320 x 480 BUT only for the first time the Augmented Reality view appeared. Subsequent times that the AR view appears, the code works.

I am not sure what the heck is going on and why setting the frame of the displayView not affecting the view at all FOR THE FIRST TIME it is shown.

I'm hoping someone else has experienced this problem before and possibly solved it.

This is my code:

```
- (id)initWithViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
    coordinates     = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    coordinateViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    latestHeading   = -1.0f;
    debugView       = nil;

    [self setRootViewController: vc];

    [self setDebugMode:NO];
    [self setMaximumScaleDistance: 0.0];
    [self setMinimumScaleFactor: 1.0];
    [self setScaleViewsBasedOnDistance: YES];
    [self setRotateViewsBasedOnPerspective: YES];
    [self setMaximumRotationAngle: M_PI / 6.0];

    //CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

    NSLog(@"inside initWithViewController");    

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait)
    {
        NSLog(@"Orientation portrait");
    }
    else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        NSLog(@"orientation right");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
        [self setCurrentOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];
    }
    else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"orientation upsidedown");             
    }
    else if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
        NSLog(@"orientation left");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
        [self setCurrentOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
    }

    //[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];


    //NSLog(@"In AR view, device orientation = %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]);

    //[self setDisplayView: [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: screenRect]];
    //[self setCurrentOrientation:UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight];

    displayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-80, 80, 480, 320)]; 

    [displayView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:1.0 alpha:0.5]];

    NSLog(@"displayView x = %f", displayView.frame.origin.x);
    NSLog(@"displayView y = %f", displayView.frame.origin.y);
    NSLog(@"displayView width = %f", displayView.frame.size.width);
    NSLog(@"displayView height = %f", displayView.frame.size.height);

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange:) name: UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    [[self rootViewController] setView:displayView];
    //[[self rootViewController] setView:[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)]];

    //[[rootViewController view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    CLLocation *newCenter = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:37.41711 longitude:-122.02528];
    [self setCenterLocation: newCenter];
    [newCenter release];

    [self startListening];

    [self deviceOrientationUpdate];

    startLocation = nil;
    i = 0;
    objImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)];
    //[objImageView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];

    blnHasRotated = NO;

    return self;
}
```

The full code can be seen here: pastebin.com/g0eXJaPq